# Unzip All Files In A Directory

Tags: linux, shell, wildcard, unzip

I have a directory of ZIP files (created on a Windows machine). I can manually unzip them using `unzip filename`, but how can I unzip all the ZIP files in the current folder via the shell?

Using Ubuntu Linux Server.

Comment: for windows in powershell: Get-ChildItem 'path to folder' -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'path to extract' -Force

Answer (score 557, accepted):

This works in bash, according to [this link](http://linux-journal.blogspot.com/2005/04/unzip-all-zip-files-in-directory.html):

> unzip \*.zip

Comment: I needed the backslash with [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/). I don't know of a reason you'd need it if you're using Bash.

Comment: What will happen with duplicate files? I guess it will just override?

Comment: Works great on macOS 

Comment: Worked for me in zsh

Comment: When doing this I get filename not matched for all the zip files in the directory

Comment: The version with quotes worked for me on WSL. The filenames also had spaces in them, FWIW.

Comment: When you get the `Filename not matched`, just wrap the pattern in single quotes: `unzip '*.zip'`

Answer (score 168):

Just put in some quotes to escape the wildcard:

```
unzip "*.zip"
```

Comment: +1 This one worked for me. I had to unzip filenames with a particular format while restricting the rest. I just kept the matching format within double quotes and it worked like charm. Output tells me the number of archives successfully processed.

Comment: Worked beautifully on Ubuntu for Windows subsystem, 11/18/2018. Top answer didn't work.

Comment: how can we extract them in directories with their respective names?

Comment: It is important to use quotes or single quotes. Sample: `unzip '*.zip' -d ./myfolder/`.

Answer (score 117):

The shell script below extracts all zip files in the current directory into new dirs with the filename of the zip file, i.e.:

The following files:

```
myfile1.zip
myfile2.zip
```

Will be extracted to:

```
./myfile1/files...
./myfile2/files...
```

**Shell script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
for zip in *.zip
do
  dirname=`echo $zip | sed 's/\.zip$//'`
  if mkdir "$dirname"
  then
    if cd "$dirname"
    then
      unzip ../"$zip"
      cd ..
      # rm -f $zip # Uncomment to delete the original zip file
    else
      echo "Could not unpack $zip - cd failed"
    fi
  else
    echo "Could not unpack $zip - mkdir failed"
  fi
done
```

---

[Source Gist](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/suvefuxuxo.bash)

---

#### Usage:

```
cd /dir/with/zips
wget -O - https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/suvefuxuxo.bash | bash
```

Comment: This is the thing to conquer all things.  Can't believe it's not voted higher

Comment: This doesn't deal with spaces in filenames.

Comment: Just add quotes `"` to the filename

Comment: the ` saved my day! thanks! I am doing some loop, unzip, perform an action, copy, grep something, remove. The thing missing was how to go from file.gz to file as a variable in the bash script

Comment: This should be the ultimate answer to all unzipping anywhere and anytime, why is this not the accepted answer? :)

Comment: This is a more complex version of j-i-l's answer. Just use the -d flag from unzip and shell string manipulation for the folder name

Answer (score 50):

unzip *.zip, or if they are in subfolders, then something like

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;
```

Comment: unzip does wildcard processing so a file called "*.zip" won't do what you expect.

Comment: Actually this will do exactly what is expected, the result of the find operation is being passed to unzip

Comment: This will extract all the zip files in current directory, what if I want the zip files (present in subfolders) to be extracted in the respective subfolders ?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari I addressed your comment in [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845911/1622937).

Comment: for `gzip'ed` files, use `gunzip -rfk .` for recursive unzipping inside respective folders

Answer (score 49):

Unzip all `.zip` files and store the content in a new folder with the same name and in the same folder as the `.zip` file:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

*This is an extension of [@phatmanace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2374816/1622937) and addresses [@RishabhAgrahari's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374772/unzip-all-files-in-a-directory#comment84649278_2374816)*:

> *This will extract all the zip files in current directory, what if I want the zip files (present in subfolders) to be extracted in the respective subfolders ?*

Comment: for `gzip'ed` files, use `gunzip -rfk .` for recursive unzipping inside respective folders

Comment: Getting `find: illegal option -- n` using **UnZip 6.00** - anybody else?

Comment: `find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;` You forgot the directory listing.

Comment: this worked for me, above script / solutions dont.

Answer (score 23):

```
for i in *.zip; do
  newdir="${i:0:-4}" && mkdir "$newdir"
  unzip "$i" -d  "$newdir"
done
```

This will unzip all the zip archives into new folders named with the filenames of the zip archives.

`a.zip` `b.zip` `c.zip` will be unzipped into `a` `b` `c` folders respectively.

Comment: This one worked for my use case, needs more up votes. The other approaches do not place the extracted files in a folder of the same name, as expected, but there are some cases where using this approach to separate the folders will be needed.

Answer (score 8):

`aunpack -e *.zip`, with `atool` installed.
Has the advantage that it deals intelligently with errors, and always unpacks into subdirectories unless the zip contains only one file . Thus, there is no danger of polluting the current directory with masses of files, as there is with `unzip` on a zip with no directory structure.

Comment: `aunpack -e -D *.zip` if you want each zip to get its own output dir regardless of the number of files in it (similar to default behavior of ExtractAll in Windows)

Answer (score 8):

In any POSIX shell, this will unzip into a different directory for each zip file:

```
for file in *.zip
do
    directory="${file%.zip}"
    unzip "$file" -d "$directory"
done
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `for file in *.zip; do unzip "$file" -d "${file%.zip}"; done`

Answer (score 5):

`for file in 'ls *.zip'; do unzip "${file}" -d "${file:0:-4}"; done`

Comment: Great to me. Unzip in their subfolders respectively

Comment: It's safer to just do `for file in *.zip; do ...` right?

Answer (score 5):

If by 'current directory' you mean the directory in which the zip file is, then I would use this command:

```sh
find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip {} \;
```

excerpt from find's [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html)

```
-execdir command ;
-execdir command {} +
```

> Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find. This a much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files. As with the -exec option, the '+' form of -execdir will build a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given invocation of command will only list files that exist in the same subdirectory. If you use this option, you must ensure that your $PATH environment variable does not reference the current directory; otherwise, an attacker can run any commands they like by leaving an appropriately-named file in a directory in which you will run -execdir.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner without using `ls` that creates folders with the zip names for the files. It works for any zips in the current directory.

```sh
for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z" -d "${z%".zip"}"; done
```

You can add it to your `.bashrc`

```sh
alias unzip_all='for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z" -d "${z%".zip"}"; done'
```

Inspiration taken from:

`Method #2: Unzipping Multiple Files from Linux Command Line Using Shell For Loop (Long Version)` in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-unzipping-many-zip-files/

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
for file in `ls *.Zip`; do
unzip ${file} -d ${unzip_dir_loc}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are `gzip'd`. Then just use:

```
gunzip -rfk .
```

from the root directory to recursively extract files in respective directories by keeping the original ones (or remove `-k` to delete them)

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of [Pedro Lobito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797495) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29248777/4934640) using [How to loop through a directory recursively to delete files with certain extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638874/how-to-loop-through-a-directory-recursively-to-delete-files-with-certain-extensi) teachings:

```
shopt -s globstar
root_directory="."

for zip_file_name in **/*.{zip,sublime\-package}; do
    directory_name=`echo $zip_file_name | sed 's/\.\(zip\|sublime\-package\)$//'`
    printf "Unpacking zip file \`$root_directory/$zip_file_name\`...\n"

    if [ -f "$root_directory/$zip_file_name" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$root_directory/$directory_name"
        unzip -o -q "$root_directory/$zip_file_name" -d "$directory_name"

        # Some files have the executable flag and were not being deleted because of it.
        # chmod -x "$root_directory/$zip_file_name"
        # rm -f "$root_directory/$zip_file_name"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
sudo apt-get install unzip 

unzip file.zip -d path_to_destination_folder
```

to unzip a folder in linux

Comment: This will only unzip single file. Question is to unzip all folders

Comment: To be fair, the title "Unzip All Files In A Directory" *could* be ambiguous and also mean to "Unzip a single archive into a separate directory".

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $i; done
```

Comment: *Dangerous* use of ls. What if you have a file called "-j -o -d  .. jackass.zip"

Answer (score -3):

To unzip all files in a directory just type this cmd in terminal:

```
unzip '*.zip'
```

Comment: this answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376135/6948900