# ffmpeg: Transcoding multiple input files to multiple output files with single command

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert three files with a **single command**. I used the following command:

`-i "C:\fil1.mp4" -i "C:\file2.mp4" -i "C:\file3.mp4" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ar 22050 -ac 2 -b:v 128k -r 20 -s 176x144 -y file1.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ar 22050 -ac 2 -b:v 128k -r 20 -s 176x144 -y file2.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ar 22050 -ac 2 -b:v 128k -r 20 -s 176x144 -y file3.mp4`

but it converts the first files with names **fil1.mp4**, **fil2.mp4**, **fil3.mp4** but I want **all** files should be convert with its output file names.

Comment: With Bash you can use [brace expansion](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion) to run `ffmpeg` on a range of files: `for i in MVI_{2967..2970}.MOV; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -crf 24 ~/"$i"; done`

Answer (score 5):

Using `-map` helps with specifying which input goes with which output.

I used this code to convert multiple audio files:

```
ffmpeg -i infile1 -i infile2 -map 0 outfile1 -map 1 outfile2
```

also use `-map_metadata` to specify the metadata stream:

```
ffmpeg -i infile1 -i infile2 -map_metadata 0 -map 0 outfile1 -map_metadata 1 -map 1 outfile2
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with creating multiple videos from multiple audio files and a single image? `-y -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -f image2 -loop 1 -r 2 -i imagefile.png -shortest -c:a aac -c:v mpeg4 -crf 18 -preset veryfast -movflags faststart -map 0 output1.mp4 -map1 output2.mp4`

Comment: Hmm not sure. Probably. If you can't find a question like that already posted, I would suggest posing that question on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote bash script for it.

You can modify as you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE_DIR=$HOME/Videos/mov
OUTPUT_DIR=$BASE_DIR/avi
FILES=$(ls $BASE_DIR | grep .MOV)

for FILE in $FILES
do
    FILENAME="${FILE:0:-4}"
    ffmpeg -i $BASE_DIR/$FILE $OUTPUT_DIR/$FILENAME.avi
done
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Consider checking your (overly complex) script with shellcheck.net. There are several issues to address.

Comment: The question explicitly states that ffmpeg should only be invoked once. Your solution invokes it once per input file.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried David Blum's script, there was a problem with spaces in filenames.  Here's my modified script that uses `basename` to remove the file extension from filenames.  It operates on the current directory, assuming a subdirectory called 'avi':

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT_DIR=./avi

#IFS=$'\n'  # split only on newlines
for FILE in *MOV
do
    FILENAME=`basename "${FILE}" .MOV`
    ffmpeg -i  "$FILE" "$OUTPUT_DIR/$FILENAME.avi"
    #echo $FILENAME
done
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg) might help you simplify this command.

Answer (score 1):

find ./ -name "*.wav" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a libopus {}.opus \;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using `Different parallel outputs` as in the [FFMPEG documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) ?

Comment: Thank you for involvement. **cubitouch** you can see my command fulfill the criteria which is given in FFMPEG documentation as `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2\
 -acodec .. -vcodec .. output1\
 -acodec .. -vcodec .. output2\
 -acodec .. -vcodec .. output3`.

Comment: @Abubakar Why don't you try factorise the "-acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ar 22050 -ac 2 -b:v 128k -r 20 -s 176x144" part, and try parallelize the encodings ?

Comment: Sorry i could not do that.

Comment: And what about Parallel Encoding ? (see http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-April/014898.html)

Answer (score 0):

When I have more files to work, I create a spreadsheet sheet and I do the command with "holes".

Every hole match to a file (filename).

I copy/paste in a file which become a script.

I know it is not perfect bet if it can help you.

Comment: What do you mean by holes?