# Cannot convert FLAC to WAV and keep all all metadata with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am lack of music format knowledge but I wonder if we can convert FLAC to WAV and keep all metadata e.g. title, artist with "ffmpeg" commandline tool.

Here is the command I use:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input-song-name.flac -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -map_metadata 0 output-song-name.wav
```

Explain:

```
-i => input file
-acodec pcm_s16le => pcm 16bit
-ar 44100 => convert audio rate to 44100
-map_metadata 0 => take the metadata from the first input file
```

It converts flac to 44100 Hz, 16-bit stereo format CD quality, 1411kbps but there is no metadata in an output .wav file.
I wonder if I set wrong option or wav does not support metatada.
I would be glad if someone can help me on this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you try to convert your file to mp3 ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109837/convert-flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg-keeping-all-metadata?rq=1

Comment: According to [this post's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1389592/1114414), we can't do this with a wav file.

Comment: @SirinatPaphatsirinatthi Thank you so much for your help. It points me to the answer.