# FFmpeg: Encode multiple video files at once (batch)

Tags: bash, encoding, ffmpeg

How do I encode multiple video files in one batch with `ffmpeg`, using the same settings?

I found this [one-line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/4909923) that converts .avi files in the current folder to .mov. Note that I want to encode `.mov -> .mov` :

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.mov}.mov" ; done
```

I wish to use the following settings for encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -crf 20 -af "volume=25dB, highpass=f=200, equalizer=f=50:width_type=h:width=100:g=-15" -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k OUTPUT-ENCODED.MOV
```

Possible ways to prevent overwriting:

- Add `-ENCODED` to the end of the filename before the file extension
- Rename the files to something sequential, like `OUTPUT01.MOV`, `OUTPUT02.MOV`, etc
- Put the encoded files in a directory subfolder but with the same file names

Comment: So what? You already have all the pieces, and you propose three possible ways, all of which are okay. So what do you want *from us* exactly?

Comment: Assembly of those pieces, because I don't know how.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.mov}-ENCODED.mov"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freely manipulate the output file `${i%.mov}.mov` - here, the "key ingredient" is that the statement `${i%.mov}` yields content of variable `i` with the shortest match of `.mov` deleted from the back. For details see this [tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) on manipulating strings in bash.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is what I did: `for i in *.MOV; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -crf 20 -af "volume=25dB, highpass=f=200, equalizer=f=50:width_type=h:width=100:g=-15" -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k "${i%.MOV}-ENCODED.MOV"; done`