# Quickly check the integrity of video files inside a directory with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm desperately searching for a convenient method to check the integrity of .mp4 files inside a specific directory with folders in it. Both the names of the .mp4 files and the folders contain spaces, special characters and numbers.

I've already found a proper ffmpeg command to quickly identify a damaged .mp4 file, taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4#comment1367300_100290):
`ffmpeg -v error -i filename.mp4 -map 0:1 -f null - 2>error.log`

If the created error.log contains some entries, then the file is obviously corrupted. The opposite would be an empty error.log.

The next step would be to apply this command to every .mp4 file within the folder and its subfolders. Some guides, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/ffmpeg-convert-entire-directory) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114908/bash-script-to-convert-all-flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg), do describe how to apply a ffmpeg command recursively, but my coding skills are limited, so therefore I can't find a way to combine these commands to get the following:

A way to test all .mp4 files inside a folder (recursively) with the aforementioned ffmpeg command, that should create .log files, only if a video file does contain errors (read has some content) and it should inherit the name of the broken file, to know which file is corrupted.

Using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10.

Comment: Do you need a batch script (Windows) or a shell script (Unix)?

Comment: A shell script, since I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A similar question but on the suitable SE network website: [How can I check the integrity of a video file (avi, mpeg, mp4...)?](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4)

Comment: A GUI wrapper for `ffmpeg` to batch scan video files for integrity within a selected directory: https://github.com/nhershy/CorruptVideoFileInspector

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this command:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -v error -i "{}" -map 0:1 -f null - 2>error.log \;
```

The `find` command finds all files in the current directory recursively which correspond to the given pattern: `"*.mp4"`. After `-exec` comes the command you want to run for all files. `"{}"` substitutes the name of the current file, where the quotes allow spaces in file names. The command has to end with `\;`.

EDIT:

The code above generates only one log file, which makes it impossible to know which file was broken. To instead create separate `.log` files for each of the `.mp4` files, you can use the `{}` symbol one more time:

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c "ffmpeg -v error -i '{}' -map 0:1 -f null - 2>'{}.log'" \;
```

Comment: Andrea, thanks for responding fast! Your command works only partially: While it takes into account all files inside a folder with its subfolders, only one error.log is created for all files. The bad thing is, that I can't identify the broken video files from the content of this .log file alone, because it shows me only the broken bytes of a file, but not the filename itself. Therefore I'm searching for a command, that will create a separate .log file for each damaged video file, that will have the same name as the damaged video file.

Comment: This time your updated command created a single .log file called {}.log. Something went wrong.

Comment: @dmt I updated the second command, try it! If that still does not work, my last idea is to use the first version with a more verbose logging level: `-v verbose` instead of `-v error`. This way you'd have one log file, but more information, so you would hopefully see which file contains the broken bytes.

Comment: Your updated command didn't work very well again, but the first one with `-v verbose` finally was sufficient to find the broken video files. Huge thanks!

Comment: Try adding an explicit star.  This avoids the implicit `./` that disrupts the redirection:```find * -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c "ffmpeg -v error -i {} -map 0:1 -f null - 2>{}.log" \;```

Comment: Better still: `find *.mp4 -exec sh -c "ffmpeg -v error -i {} -map 0:1 -f null - 2>{}.log" \;`

Comment: In case you have space in file name `find -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c "ffmpeg -v error -i '{}' -map 0:1 -f null - 2>'{}.log'" \;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the 2nd command above is brilliant, it creates a .log per file, and does it very rapidly. The `-f null` is responsible for reading files rapidly and just checking frame integrity. Without that flag, it would take almost as long as to watch the movie.

Answer (score 12):

I recently met with the same problem, but I think there's a simple hack to find out which files are broken:

```
find -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c "echo '{}' >> errors.log; ffmpeg -v error -i '{}' -map 0:1 -f null - 2>> errors.log" \;
```

This way the errors follow the filename (and path).

Comment: For even better formatting sourcery
`find . -name "*.mp4" -exec sh -c "echo '{}\t\c' >> errors.log; ffmpeg -v error -i '{}' -map 0:1 -f null - 2>> errors.log;echo ''>>errors.log" \;`

Answer (score 2):

```
find /dir/subdir -iname "*.mp4" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do ERR=`ffprobe -v error "$file" 2>&1`; if [ "$ERR" != "" ]; then echo "$file"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the other answers using `ffmpeg` to recode to `null` format is that they take a long time. A quick way would be to generate thumbnails for all the videos, and see where thumbnail generation fails.

```sh
find . -iname "*.mp4" | while read -r line; do 
  line=`echo "$line" | sed -r 's/^\W+//g'`; 
  echo 'HERE IT IS ==>' "$line"; 
  if ffmpeg -i "$line" -t 2 -r 0.5 %d.jpg; 
    then echo "DONE for" "$line"; 
  else echo "FAILED for" "$line" >>error.log; 
  fi; 
done;
```

This method turned out to be much FASTER than other methods.

However, there is a CAVEAT. This method can yield wrong results, because sometimes thumbnail can be generated even for corrupt files. E.g. if the video file is corrupted only at the end, this method will fail.

Comment: @llogan This answer only uses thumbnail generation as an alternative to the null encoder. The goal is still finding corrupt video files, although it's much less informative than the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A batch file for Windows systems, assuming that ffmpeg is somewhere in your path:

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -v error -i "%%f" -map 0:1 -f null - 2>out.txt
    if errorlevel 1 (
        type out.txt
        echo   %%f
    )
)
if exist out.txt del out.txt 1>nul 2>nul
pause
```

This will list the error followed by the indented file name only for those files in error.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this here mainly for me and maybe other people that want to use ffmpeg to batch find in multiple folders videos with errors or corrupt files, create a subfolder and move the files in that subfolder.

Here is my bash script for recursive find mp4 files with errors and move them inside 00errors folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOTPATH="/mnt/f/00test/" # manually define root  path to your folder that has subfolders
for subdir in *; do
  cd ${ROOTPATH}${subdir} 
  mkdir 00errors
  
  for path in *.mp4; do

    ffmpeg error -i "${path}"
    RC=$?

    if [ "${RC}" -ne "0" ]; then
        # Do something to handle the error.
        mv ${path} ./00errors
    fi

  done
  cd ../
done
```

Edit:

In the meantime I found this app HBBatchBeast for HandBrake and FFmpeg/FFprobe (Windows, macOS, Linux & Docker)

https://github.com/HaveAGitGat/HBBatchBeast

Comment: your script moves EVERY video from a folder to a subfolder, regardless if the video is corrupted or not 