# How to Loop Prorocess FFMpeg in Windows?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, encode, watermark

I want to install a watermark in all my videos. I have 25 videos. but I am tired when using ffmpeg 1 time 1 time. I want multi in 1 script. How to ?

```
ffmpeg -i video01.mkv -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay = 10: 10" output01.mkv
ffmpeg -i video02.mkv -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay = 10: 10" output02.mkv
```

I use the script. but I am confused so that all my videos are run only 1 script

help me

Comment: This has been asked many times on this site. For example, see [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273691/1109017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if I have understood well your question, but if yes, you would need something like this:

```bat
ffmpeg -i !_input_file! -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay = 10: 10" !_output_file!
```

Full code:

```bat
:: this is one line command: cd /d “%~dp0”

:: make system go to drive(d) and path/folder(p) of current file (%0)

@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

cd /d “%~dp0”

:: looping from 1 by 1 to 25 (leading with 0 file 1-9 to input/output files)

for /l %%i in ( 1 1 25 ) do (

     if %%i leq 9 ( 

           set _input_file=video0%%i.mkv
           set _output_file=output0%%i.mkv

          ) else ( 

           set _input_file=video%%i.mkv
           set _output_file=output%%i.mkv

          )

     ffmpeg -i !_input_file! -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay = 10: 10" -v error -stats -vn !_output_file!

     )
```