# Extract frames from multiple video-files in Windows Batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

So, I tried a few lines of code in a Windows batch file to extract frames from MP4-files.

`ffmpeg -i "filename.mp4" "frames/out-%%06d.jpg"` works on just one file.

`ffmpeg -i "*.mp4" "frames/out-%%06d.jpg"`does not work at all.

How do I get it to play nice with multiple inputfiles?

Comment: Something like [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)`%%I in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~I" "frames\%%~nI-%%06d.jpg"`?

Comment: It runs, yay! Thanks. Will see if it continues with the second file, but looks good.

Comment: Similar to [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273691/1109017)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```bat
for %%A in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%A" "frames\%%~nA_out-%%06d.jpg"
```

Note: Your example was not good as it will continuously replace file `out-%%06d.jpg`!

`%%~nA` is the filename of the `mp4` file is being processed.

Type `for /?` in a fresh cmd for more information.