# ffmpeg mp4 convert script with sub directories

Tags: file, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have a folder with multiple subfolders with mkv files

main directory

then

Directory A
  Dir B
  Dir C
  Dir D
  Dir E
  Dir F
  Dir G

I need a script that will search all directories for .mkv and convert to .mp4

i currently have this script

`for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a aac -q:a 2 -c:v copy "${file%.m    kv}.mp4"; done`

but it only works if the .sh file is placed in each dir

Comment: You can use `find`. Here is a [simplistic example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105794/1109017).

Comment: So it would be find - name for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a aac -q:a 2 -c:v copy "${file%.m kv}.mp4"; done

Comment: thanks but when i run that terminal doesnt even open

Comment: I need to run it as a .sh file executable

Comment: Here's the output wheelzi@wheelzi:~$ cd /media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd/
wheelzi@wheelzi:/media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd$ find *.mkv -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a aac -q:a 2 -c:v copy {}.mp4 \;
find: ‘*.mkv’: No such file or directory
wheelzi@wheelzi:/media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd$

Comment: wheelzi@wheelzi:/media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd/complete$ find *.mkv -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a aac -q:a 2 -c:v copy {}.mp4 \;
find: ‘*.mkv’: No such file or directory
wheelzi@wheelzi:/media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd/complete$

Comment: wheelzi@wheelzi:/media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd/complete$ find *.mkv -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a aac -q:a 2 -c:v copy {}.mp4 \; find: ‘*.mkv’: No such file or directory wheelzi@wheelzi:/media/2be833ff-cb77-407c-974e-d9bd0df8d6b2/dl/sabnzbd/complete$ when I add the output here the *. Is changed to.

Comment: No but the are in the directories in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mkv" -exec ffmpeg -y -i {} -c:a aac -q:a 2 -c:v copy {}.mp4 \;
```

Comment: works brilliant thank u... can i make this work with sabnzbd post processing script? if u know

Comment: @burrome Not sure. Never heard of a sabnzbd post processing script.