# What does the variable ${i%.*} mean in terminal?

Tags: variables, ffmpeg, terminal

This shell command converts all .avi to .mp4 as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg) by @llogan

Can someone explain how **${i%.*}** works? 
In particular, what does % do?

```
for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [BashGuide/Parameters/Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

> `${parameter%pattern}`
>   The `pattern` is matched against the end of
>   `parameter`. The result is the expanded value of `parameter` with the
>   shortest match deleted.

From [How do I do string manipulations in bash?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100):

> The `%` means "remove the shortest possible match from the end of the
>   variable's contents"

In other words, if the expanded value of `parameter` (`i` in your case) is `myvideo.avi`, then `%.*` will result in `myvideo`. This is so the output file does not end up being named `myvideo.avi.mp4`, and instead is named `myvideo.mp4`.