# Is there a function to add a title to multiple videos? FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm getting started with FFMPEG to add a title video to a few dozen videos I have. What would be the proper command to do this?

Answer (score 0):

## Use the concat demuxer

There are several methods to join/merge/concatenate one video to another. This method uses the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) in `ffmpeg` to join the title video to the main video. Although there are several steps, it has the advantage that it does not re-encode the video you are adding a title to. So the process is quick and the quality is preserved.

---

## Example

See the attributes of the video you want to add a title video to. In this example it is named `main.mp4`. When making the title video you will need to ensure that it matches the attributes of the video you want to add a title to.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4
...
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 988 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
```

Generate the title video. Make sure the title video matches the attributes of the main file so it can concatenate properly. This example uses the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) and [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) source filters to make 5 seconds of black video and silent audio, and the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter to make text:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:rate=30000/1001:duration=5:color=black -f lavfi -i anullsrc=sample_rate=44100:channel_layout=stereo -vf "drawtext=text='your title':fontcolor=white:fontsize=48:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -shortest title.mp4
```

Make a text file named `input.txt`. This will be used by the concat demuxer and lists the files that you want to concatenate.

```
file 'title.mp4'
file 'main.mp4'
```

Finally, concatenate the title video to the main video with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

---

## Batch mode

`ffmpeg` does not have a batch mode to automatically do this for a folder of videos. However, it can be done with shell scripting but that is a whole new topic that deserves its own question. See [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661/) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Okay, so I'm completely new to this so can you explain what main.mp4 and the input.txt as well? Thanks.

Comment: @SamayLakhani `main.mp4` is just an example name for a single video that a title is to be added to. `input.txt` is a simple text file containing a list of files that should be concatenated together. In my example it will join `title.mp4` to `main.mp4`.