# Delete subtiltes from an MKV with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

Can anonye tell me a way to delete all subtiles except from a number of specified languages from a MKV with FFMPEG, preferrably in way that this could be done sequentially from mutltiple files ?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) option. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -map -0:s -map 0:s:m:language:fra -c copy output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` Select all streams from input 0 (which is `input.mkv` in this example).
- `-map -0:s` Negative mapping that omits all subtitle streams from input 0.
- `-map 0:s:m:language:fra` means `input 0:subtitles:metadata:language:french` which selects all subtitles streams with French language metadata.
- `-c copy` Enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode to only re-mux and not re-encoding.

As for sequential usage the answer depends on your OS. See [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661/) for many examples.