# Add subtitles to multiple files at once

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder with episodes called `ep` and a folder with subtitles called `sub`
Each episode has corresponding subtitles and i need to bulk add them with ffmpeg.

I've read that i can add subtitles with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf "ass=subtitle.ass" out.avi
```

But that only does it one file at a time.
Is there a bulk variant?

Some useful info:
`ls ep` prints

```
<series name> - Ep<episode number>.mkv
```

`ls sub` prints

```
<series name> - Ep<episode number>.ass
```

Comment: Not possible with ffmpeg by itself. Can be done with a *for loop*. Answer depends on your OS.

Comment: @llogan yeah i figured i'd make it with a script, i created it.

Comment: Sounds like you found a solution. Consider adding it as an answer to your question, or mark it as a duplicate of [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661/) if you think one of those answers suffices.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small sh script that will do this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

SUBTITLES_FOLDER=sub
EPISODES_FOLDER=ep
OUTPUT_FOLDER=out

for i in "$EPISODES_FOLDER"/*.mkv; do
    sub="$SUBTITLES_FOLDER/$(echo "$i" | sed 's/mkv$/ass/')"
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "$sub" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -y "$OUTPUT_FOLDER/$i" &
done
```

**Note the '&' at the end of the ffmpeg command: it makes sure ffmpeg runs in parallel** (is this the correct term for it?)

You may want to modify the file extensions and check if ffmpeg supports subtitles with your format, the rest will be done by itself.