# How to use ffmpeg stream copy within bash "for loop"?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, ffmpeg

ok i have this and it works but it's slow

```
for i in *.mov;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  ffmpeg -i "$i" "${name}.mp4"
done
```

I want it to convert with these ffmpeg options

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter expansion is sufficient; you don't need pipelines involving `cut`.

```
for i in *.mov; do
    name=${i%%.mov}  # i=foo.mov => name=foo
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "$name.mp4"
done
```

Comment: Ok thanks! But it stil slow and I read that if "-vcodec copy -acodec" you use it's going to convert much faster. I want to import in premiere

Comment: You can run instances of of `ffmpeg` in parallel; there is minimal overhead involved in the actual shell.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but you should be able to do them in parallel with **GNU Parallel** if it's too slow and you have a multicore CPU:

```
parallel ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec copy -acodec copy {.}.mp4 ::: *.mov
```

If you want to see what it would do first, without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec copy -acodec copy {.}.mp4 ::: *.mov
```

Note: On macOS, install these two packages simply with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install ffmpeg
brew install parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

- `-c copy` is the same as `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`.
- Adapted from [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)