# How to batch convert .ogg files to .wav using a command line utility?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, terminal, data-conversion, afconvert

I have a bunch of files:

```
dir/file1.ogg
dir/file2.ogg
...
```

How could I convert them to .wav files

```
dir/wav/file1.wav
dir/wav/file2.wav
...
```

by using a console command? Now I'm using OSX, but I need the answer for Windows as well.

Comment: For macOS & Linux: modified from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/) in duplicate question: `mkdir wav; for i in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "wav/${i%.*}.wav"; done`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sample code is close.

```sh
for i in *.ogg; do
  ffmpeg -acodec libvorbis -i "$i" -acodec pcm_s16le "${i%ogg}wav"
done
```

This decodes with ffmpeg and generates an output file name that removes the trailing `ogg` and appends a trailing `wav`.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i example.ogg example.wav` was suffice

Comment: @ash17 – Yes, ffmpeg should be able to decipher the intent from the extensions. I was being explicit in case other extensions were used.