# How to I convert all audio tracks to eac3 and keep all subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm not familiar with ffmpeg, but came across this script that takes in the file and creates an output with eac3 audio.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Dolby Digital Plus Muxer"
echo "Developed by @kdcloudy, not affiliated with Dolby Laboratories"
echo "Enter the file name to be converted: "
read filepath
if [! -d $filepath]
then
exit $err
fi

ffmpeg -i $filepath -vn ddp.eac3
ffmpeg -i $filepath -i ddp.eac3 -vcodec copy -c:a eac3 -map 0:s -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
rm ddp.eac3
```

I'd like to know what to modify in this code to ensure all the subtitles are copied from the original file and all the available audio tracks are converted to eac3 and added to the output.mp4 file.
For the subtitles copying I tried -map but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need one `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a eac3 -c:s copy output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` Selects all streams. Otherwise only one stream per stream type will be selected. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more into on `-map`.
- `-c:v copy` [Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) all video.
- `-c:a eac3` Encodes all audio to E-AC-3.
- `-c:s copy` Stream copy all subtitles.

For compatibility this assumes that the input and output are both Matroska (`.mkv`).

That script is not great. Here's a cleaner, simpler version (not that I think a script is necessary for this):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./eac3 input.mkv output.mkv

ffmpeg -i "$1" -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a eac3 -c:s copy "$2"
```

If you want to convert a whole directory see [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm trying to convert mkv files to mp4 w/ ac3. When I ran the script I got  

`Could not find tag for codec ass in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- `

And when I removed `-c:s copy` I got

`Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2`

Comment: @KushalSaiGunturi I made two assumptions: 1) you wanted MP4 output format. 2) You wanted to, *"ensure all the subtitles are copied from the original file"*, so I assumed input and output are the same format. MP4 only supports "mov_text" subtitles, so you can't stream copy ASS to MP4. So if you want MP4 change `-c:s copy` to `-c:s mov_text`. Note that support for subtitles in MP4 is not widely supported so your player may not play them. Or output to .mkv instead of .mp4 and the original command will work.

Comment: I used this command on a MKV file with 1 Video, 4 Audio (all EAC3) and 1 Subtitle Stream :-

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -c:s copy output.mkv

I get following error :-

[matroska @ 0000011ce929e600] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:4 --
[libmp3lame @ 0000011ce99b4600] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
[libmp3lame @ 0000011ce93dc980] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a simpler way to achieve this it to copy all with `-c copy` and then override a specific stream (for example an audio track) or streams (for example all audio tracks).

This way one does not need to specify `-c:v copy` or `-c:s copy`.

Lets take for example the file `video1.mkv`, which has the following streams:

```bash
Input #0:
  Stream #0:0: Video h264
  Stream #0:1: Audio aac (italian)
  Stream #0:2: Audio aac (german)
  Stream #0:3: Subtitle  (english)
```

I can the convert **all** audio tracks to `eac3` this way:

`-c:a eac3`

```bash
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 video1.eac3.mkv
```

`ffmpeg` will automatically override the general `-c copy` and use the last given option for all audio streams.
A message like this will be printed:

```bash
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 1, only the last option '-c:a eac3' will be used.
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 2, only the last option '-c:a eac3' will be used.
```

Output stream mapping is shown as follows:

```bash
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> eac3 (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (aac (native) -> eac3 (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
```

---

In case only the **first** audio should be converted:

`-c:a:0 eac3`

```bash
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a:0 eac3 video1.ita-eac3.mkv
```

`ffmpeg` message:

```bash
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 1, only the last option '-c:a:0 eac3' will be used.
```

Output stream mapping:

```bash
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> eac3 (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
```

---

In case only the **second** audio stream should be converted:

`-c:a:1 eac3`

```bash
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a:1 eac3 video1.ger-eac3.mkv
```

`ffmpeg` message:

```bash
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 2, only the last option '-c:a:1 eac3' will be used.
```

Output stream mapping:

```bash
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (aac (native) -> eac3 (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
```

---

As user `llogan` pointed out, a script might be unnecessary for this task.
A `for` loop can be used to convert multiple files:

**I added `echo` at the beginning to simulate what it will do.**

```bash
for VIDEO in video1.mkv video2.mkv video3.mkv video4.mkv video5.mkv
do
  echo ffmpeg -i "$VIDEO" -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 "${VIDEO%.*}.eac3.mkv"
done
```

```bash
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 video1.eac3.mkv
ffmpeg -i video2.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 video2.eac3.mkv
ffmpeg -i video3.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 video3.eac3.mkv
ffmpeg -i video4.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 video4.eac3.mkv
ffmpeg -i video5.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a eac3 video5.eac3.mkv
```