# FFmpeg Batch .mov > .gif conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal

I am trying to batch convert a folder of .mov's into .gif's.

Input .mov's are 1920x1080 resolution and I would like to convert to 720x480 (to save file size). I have the following code, but not sure how to add the -vf scale=720 into this code:

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -ss 1 -i "$i" "${i%.*}.gif";  done
```

The above code works, just running it through terminal. Any help on adding the scale or any other optimizations to reduce file size would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.mov; do ffmpeg -ss 1 -i "$i" -vf "fps=10,scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 "${i%.*}.gif"; done
```

Combination of:

- [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031)
- [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)