# How do you convert to the same format an entire directory with subfolders using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-processing

How to keep the file name and **the extension** the same and append `_backup` to the old file?

I have had tried this

`find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'for f; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.*}.mp4"; done' -- {} +`

but here the files would be overwritten.

I hope what I have requested is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: No, because of the different file extensions there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you append *"_backup"* to your input files first, then process the just renamed files with `ffmpeg`:

Simple for-loop to process files in current directory:

```sh
for f in *.mp4; do
  mv "$f" "${f%.*}_backup.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "${f%.*}_backup.mp4" -c copy "$f"
done

#or single-line:
for f in *.mp4; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}_backup.mp4"; ffmpeg -i "${f%.*}_backup.mp4" -c copy "$f"; done
```

`find` to process files in current directory and sub directories:

```sh
find -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c '
  f="{}"
  mv "$f" "${f%.*}_backup.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "${f%.*}_backup.mp4" -c copy "$f"
' \;

#or single-line:
find -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f%.*}_backup.mp4"; ffmpeg -i "${f%.*}_backup.mp4" -c copy "$f"' \;
```

Comment: I have tried
```find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'for f in *.mp4; do
  mv "$f" "${f%.*}_backup.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "${f%.*}_backup.mp4" -c copy "$f"
done' -- {} +```
But files in the nested folders are ignored. Do you have a fix?

Comment: @featertu You shouldn't randomly combine these commands. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yet still, nested folders are being left out. Is it a problem with my setup? Does it work for you?

Comment: @featertu With `find -name "*.mp4"` alone I get a list of all mp4-files in the current dir as well it's sub-directories. I'm not an expert on possible differences between different versions of `find`. Sorry.

Comment: You forgot `.` after `find`. 
It worked for me after adding the dot.