# Extract Creation date and time of multiple files at once

Tags: ffmpeg

$ ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags=creation_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4

This is good for one file at a time, can someone suggest while multiple files like 50 files at a time? or how to run this in a loop? When there are 50 files, it doesn't make sense to run this command 50 times inputting file name every single time. Thanks

Comment: Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/): `for i in *.mp4; do ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format=filename:stream_tags=creation_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$i"; done`. Note that `creation_time` will be printed before `filename`. I'm assuming you're using Linux or macOS.

Comment: Thanks, @llogan. This is exactly what I was looking for. Kudos!!