# Extract LUFS only from multiple file

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, terminal

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/I:/{print $2}'`
The above command extract only LUFS value from input.mp4 file. But If there are number of mp4 files, how to apply similar command to extract LUFS value only from multiple mp4 files?
Please help.

Comment: I would put this question this way, " How to extract only LUFS value from multiple mp4 files?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this answer from *How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)

```
for i in *.mp4; do echo "$i:"; ffmpeg -i "$i" -map 0:a -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/I:/{print $2}'; done
```

Example output:

```
video1.mp4:
-21.8
video2.mp4:
-21.1
video3.mp4:
-21.8
-8.3
```

- Note that `video3.mp4` contains 2 separate audio streams.
- This is assuming you can use Bash shell.
- `-map 0:a` was added to only process the audio so the video is ignored and therefore the command is faster. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Comment: Thanks a lot @llogan!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to print the output in the same line? Example:                                                      ```video1.mp4: -21.8
video2.mp4: -21.1
video3.mp4: -21.8 -8.3```

Comment: @sJoss Use the `-n` option in `echo`