# Use ffmpeg to assess media quality recursively and output to a file

Tags: ffmpeg

Would anyone mind telling me how to use ffmpeg recursively to scan my collection, assess the video quality and export all of the output data to a file? I've searched quite a bit on the web and there have been some close to what I'm looking for but not exactly. If I should be using something else, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!

J

Comment: What do you mean by *"video quality"* please? *"Your Clint Eastwood stuff is pretty good, but the Pepa Pig stuff is a bit childish"*? What sort of results are you expecting and in what format? Thank hou.

Comment: Answer depends on your OS.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The query will be ran from a Windows 10 Machine. I'm mainly looking for it to output the video file's resolution and video bit rate for each one to a file. Let me know if you need further info. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you know how to get what you want for a single file. This should help you recurse https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273691/2836621

Comment: Do you need help with the ffmpeg command, or with the batch-file? Because those are 2 different topics and therefore 2 different questions. You're expected to ask 1 question per post on Stack Overflow and you'll get a better chance for getting an answer.

Comment: If you could assist me with the ffmpeg command because I have avi, mkv & mp4 files each in individual directories inside one parent folder. I believe I can figure out how to redirect the output to file. Thanks!

Comment: @JD71 All of the ffmpeg quality metric filters (libvmaf, msad, psnr, ssim, vif, perhaps there are more) require 2 inputs: the reference video and the converted video. Are you looking for an AI based quality metric solution to determine the quality of single videos with no reference? I am not aware of anything like that in FFmpeg.

Comment: So, are you're saying it's not possible to use it with -i recursively and it output the quality of each file?

Comment: @JD71 I did not get notified of your reply (it lacked @llogan). AFAIK, FFmpeg currently does not have a method to tell you the quality of a video without another video to compare it to.