# How to convert multiple stereo audio files to mono using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mono, stereo-3d, audio-analysis

I have been trying to convert a set of audio files from stereo to mono type.Can you help by providing the command for converting all the files in the folder?

Comment: `for i in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -ac 1 "${i%.*}.wav"; done`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg)