# How to insert a text at the beginning of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

So far I've been able to find out how to add a line at the beginning of a file but that's not exactly what I want. I'll show it with an example:

**File content**

```
some text at the beginning
```

**Result**

```
<added text> some text at the beginning
```

It's similar but I don't want to create any new line with it...

I would like to do this with `sed` if possible.

Comment: Anything in here work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365/prepend-to-a-file-one-liner-shell - you don't need to use `sed`.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

`sed` can operate on an address:

```
$ sed -i '1s/^/<added text> /' file
```

What is this magical `1s` you see on every answer here? [Line addressing!](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html).

Want to add `<added text>` on the first 10 lines?

```
$ sed -i '1,10s/^/<added text> /' file
```

Or you can use [`Command Grouping`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping):

```
$ { echo -n '<added text> '; cat file; } >file.new
$ mv file{.new,}
```

Comment: To actually insert a new line: sed -i '1s/^/<added text> \n/' file

Comment: Why using -i ?? On man it says that it is for suffix. http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed

Comment: -i stands for in-place, you can append a suffix to -i to make a copy rather than overwrite. -i.new would make a new file ending with .new, but just -i would edit the file directly.

Comment: With command grouping, note the last semicolon before } .. it needs to be there, otherwise shell complaints about unexpected end of file.

Comment: Note that the sed won't work on an empty file - afaict sed can't be made to do anything at all with 0-length input.

Comment: @Jirapong It is GNU sed specific. You can achieve the same on e.g. OS X by using gsed.

Comment: @PJK thank you. You're right but gsed need to install from macport or brew first.

Comment: First solution adds to first line not to beginning of file.

Comment: What does the `1` mean in the script `sed -i '1s/^/<added text> /' file`

Comment: The flaw of this solution is that it doesn't add the text if file is empty.

Comment: What if instead of giving text directly, I have to take first line from one file and add as first line to another file ?

Comment: Love the last command grouping way. The spaces around the curl brackets are not optional!!

Comment: How to perform this in all files in current directory ?

Comment: This gives and error "sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'"

Answer (score 86):

If you want to add a line at the beginning of a file, you need to add `\n` at the end of the string in the best solution above.

The best solution will add the string, but with the string, it will not add a line at the end of a file.

```
sed -i '1s/^/your text\n/' file
```

Comment: On Mac OS, was getting error with "undefined label". Found that you need to give an extension for a backup file; see https://mkyong.com/mac/sed-command-hits-undefined-label-error-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Under Mac OS's `sed` version you have to supply backup file name with `-i` option.  One can pass just an empty string for no backup like `sed -i '' '1s/^/new test\n/' filename`

Answer (score 32):

If the file is only one line, you can use:

```
sed 's/^/insert this /' oldfile > newfile
```

If it's more than one line. one of:

```
sed '1s/^/insert this /' oldfile > newfile
sed '1,1s/^/insert this /' oldfile > newfile
```

I've included the latter so that you know how to do ranges of lines. Both of these "replace" the start line marker on their affected lines with the text you want to insert. You can also (assuming your `sed` is modern enough) use:

```
sed -i 'whatever command you choose' filename
```

to do in-place editing.

Answer (score 27):

Use subshell:

```
echo "$(echo -n 'hello'; cat filename)" > filename
```

---

Unfortunately, command substitution will remove newlines at the end of file. So as to keep them one can use:

```
echo -n "hello" | cat - filename > /tmp/filename.tmp
mv /tmp/filename.tmp filename
```

Neither grouping nor command substitution is needed.

Comment: this solution delete empty lines at the end of the file

Comment: This is the superior and simpler solution to all the other ones using `sed`, which don't work for empty files.

Comment: @dafnahaktana that's because of command substitution

Answer (score 18):

To insert just a newline:

```
sed '1i\\'
```

Comment: I wonder why the top voted answers all use s instead of i. Any downsides to this?

Comment: @Caesar Because when all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Comment: @Caesar What's the difference between them?

Comment: @HashimAziz That's kind of what I'm asking... (i is "unconditional insert", s is "match and replace". And most sed usage is `s` only, so Tobia is pointing out that people reaching for their most familiar tool is likely why `s` is more upvoted than this answer.)

Answer (score 16):

You can use `cat -`

```
printf '%s' "some text at the beginning" | cat - filename
```

Comment: This would only output the text followed by the file's content, but it does not modify the file at all.

Comment: That's a good solution, I wonder why it didn't get any upvotes. Here's mine my good sir. Also, why printf and not a simple echo ?

Comment: @ychaouche - presumably because there's no portable way to prevent `echo` from adding a newline?

Comment: I tried directing this into a file by appending `> file` to the command, it jus spammed my terminal with `"some text at the beginning"`

Comment: `printf '%s' "some text" | cat - filename > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename`

Answer (score 12):

To add a line to the top of the file:

```
sed -i '1iText to add\'
```

Comment: This includes a newline, which the questioner explicitly doesn't want.

Answer (score 12):

my two cents:

```
sed -i '1i /path/of/file.sh' filename
```

where `/path/of/file.sh` is the text you want to add.

This will work even if the string contains a forward slash `"/"`

Comment: This includes a newline, which the questioner explicitly doesn't want.

Answer (score 9):

Hi with carriage return:

```
sed -i '1s/^/your text\n/' file
```

Answer (score 9):

Note that on OS X, `sed -i <pattern> file`, fails. However, if you provide a backup extension, `sed -i old <pattern> file`, then `file` is modified in place while `file.old` is created. You can then delete `file.old` in your script.

Comment: Or sed -i '' file.  Then it'll just edit in-place and not make backups.

Comment: I've found macOS sed wants a dot to edit in place without creating a backup:

sed -i. <pattern> file

Answer (score 7):

There is a very easy way:

```
echo "your header" > headerFile.txt
cat yourFile >> headerFile.txt
```

Comment: Ow... sorry, now that I realize that you wanted to add at the beginning and not a new line.

Comment: But *I* wanted a new line. So thanks for the simplistic approach.

Answer (score 4):

**PROBLEM:** tag a file, at the top of the file, with the base name of the parent directory.

I.e., for

```
/mnt/Vancouver/Programming/file1
```

tag the top of `file1` with `Programming`.

**SOLUTION 1** -- non-empty files:

```
bn=${PWD##*/}    ## bn: basename

sed -i '1s/^/'"$bn"'\n/' <file>
```

`1s` places the text at line 1 of the file.

**SOLUTION 2** -- empty or non-empty files:

The `sed` command, above, fails on empty files.  Here is a solution, based on https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash/246841#246841

```
printf "${PWD##*/}\n" | cat - <file> > temp && mv -f temp <file>
```

Note that the `-` in the cat command is required (reads standard input: see `man cat` for more information).  Here, I believe, it's needed to take the output of the printf statement (to STDIN), and cat that and the file to temp ...  See also the explanation at the bottom of http://www.linfo.org/cat.html.

I also added `-f` to the `mv` command, to avoid being asked for confirmations when overwriting files.

To recurse over a directory:

```
for file in *; do printf "${PWD##*/}\n" | cat - $file > temp && mv -f temp $file; done
```

Note also that this will break over paths with spaces; there are solutions, elsewhere (e.g. file globbing, or `find . -type f ...` -type solutions) for those.

**ADDENDUM:**  Re: my last comment, this script will allow you to recurse over directories with spaces in the paths:

```
#!/bin/bash

## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638874/how-to-loop-through-a-directory-recursively-to-delete-files-with-certain-extensi

## To allow spaces in filenames,
##   at the top of the script include: IFS=$'\n'; set -f
##   at the end of the script include: unset IFS; set +f

IFS=$'\n'; set -f

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SET PATHS:

IN="/mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/claws-test/corpus test/"

# https://superuser.com/questions/716001/how-can-i-get-files-with-numeric-names-using-ls-command

# FILES=$(find $IN -type f -regex ".*/[0-9]*")        ## recursive; numeric filenames only
FILES=$(find $IN -type f -regex ".*/[0-9 ]*")         ## recursive; numeric filenames only (may include spaces)

# echo '$FILES:'                                      ## single-quoted, (literally) prints: $FILES:
# echo "$FILES"                                       ## double-quoted, prints path/, filename (one per line)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN LOOP:

for f in $FILES
do

  # Tag top of file with basename of current dir:
  printf "[top] Tag: ${PWD##*/}\n\n" | cat - $f > temp && mv -f temp $f

  # Tag bottom of file with basename of current dir:
  printf "\n[bottom] Tag: ${PWD##*/}\n" >> $f
done

unset IFS; set +f
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here is a solution using `ed` which does not have the problem of not working on an empty file. You can put it into a shell script just like any other answer to this question.

```
ed Test <<EOF
a

.
0i
<added text>
.
1,+1 j
$ g/^$/d
wq
EOF
```

The above script adds the text to insert to the first line, and then joins the first and second line. To avoid ed exiting on error with an invalid join, it first creates a blank line at the end of the file and remove it later if it still exists.

**Limitations:** This script does not work if `<added text>` is exactly equal to a single period.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution I found is:

```sh
echo -n "<text to add>" | cat - myFile.txt | tee myFile.txt
```

Notes:

- Remove `| tee myFile.txt` if you don't want to change the file contents.
- Remove the `-n` parameter if you want to append a full line.
- Add `&> /dev/null` to the end if you don't want to see the output (the generated file).
- This can be used to append a shebang to the file. Example:

  ```
  # make it executable (use u+x to allow only current user)
  chmod +x cropImage.ts
  # append the shebang
  echo '#''!'/usr/bin/env ts-node | cat - cropImage.ts | tee cropImage.ts &> /dev/null
  # execute it
  ./cropImage.ts myImage.png
  ```

Comment: This appends the text twice in the same line

Comment: It also replaces the content of the entire file.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam, yes it replaces the file, unless you remove the tee pipe (I have updated the answer). But It won't append the text twice. You may have run the command twice. It's working in bash and zsh.

Comment: In a for loop (in bash on OSX) it replaces the contents with only the text that should be added.
Without for it worked for me

Comment: I confirm this does not retain the original file contents

Comment: u sneaky mofo, i just overwrote my whole vhost with <text to add>, but i am bored anyway so fixing it should not be a problem

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -n "text to insert " ;tac filename.txt| tac > newfilename.txt
```

The first `tac` pipes the file backwards (last line first) so the "text to insert" appears last. The 2nd `tac` wraps it once again so the inserted line is at the beginning and the original file is in its original order.

Comment: Can you please explain how this would help Tomas with the issue?

Comment: tac | tac -- that's how non-scalable mindsets form :-(

Answer (score 1):

`cat` concatenates multiple files. `<()` sends output of a command as a file. echo doesn't add new lines with -n switch. head command with -c switch can remove trailing newline in files. Combining all these, we can insert text at the beginning and end of a file without any new lines by,

```
cat <(echo -n "line before the file") <(head -c -1 file.txt) <(echo -n "line after the file")
```

Comment: `head -c -1` doesn't work on bsd (& Macs) so please use `ghead` from `coreutils`

Answer (score 1):

thanks to all the top answers above, just a small hint:

for the `sed` approach, if you want to pass a variable while going to a newline, like what I've wanted to do with my `/etc/hosts` file, **don't forget** to use double quotes `"`

`sed -i "1s/^/127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME \n/" /etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with aliases. Add to your init rc/ env file:

```
addtail () { find . -type f ! -path "./.git/*" -exec sh -c "echo $@ >> {}" \; }
addhead () { find . -type f ! -path "./.git/*" -exec sh -c  "sed -i '1s/^/$@\n/' {}" \; }
```

Usage:

```
addtail "string to add at the beginning of file"
addtail "string to add at the end of file"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `echo` approach, if you are on macOS/BSD like me, lose the `-n` switch that other people suggest. And I like to define a variable for the text.

So it would be like this:

```sh
Header="my complex header that may have difficult chars \"like these quotes\" and line breaks \n\n "

{ echo "$Header"; cat "old.txt"; } > "new.txt"
mv new.txt old.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;dr** -

Consider using `ex`.  Since you want the front of a given line, then the syntax is basically the same as what you might find for `sed` but the option of "in place editing" is built-in.

I cannot imagine an environment where you have `sed` but not `ex`/`vi`, unless it is a MS Windows box with some special "sed.exe", maybe.

`sed` & `grep` sort of evolved from `ex` / `vi`, so it might be better to say `sed` syntax is the same as `ex`.

You can change the line number to something besides #1 or search for a line and change that one.

```
source=myFile.txt
Front="This goes IN FRONT "
man true > $source
ex -s ${source} <<EOF
1s/^/$Front/ 
wq
EOF
```

```
$ head -n 3 $source
This goes IN FRONT TRUE(1)                                                    User Commands                                                    TRUE(1)

NAME
```

Long version, I recommend `ex` (or `ed` if you are one of the cool kids).

I like `ex` because it is portable, extremely powerful, allows me to write in-place, and/or make backups all without needing GNU (or even BSD) extensions.

Additionally, if you know the `ex` way, then you know how to do it in `vi` - and probably `vim` if that is your jam.
Notice that `EOF` is not quoted when we use "i"nsert and using `echo`:

```
str="+++ TOP +++" && ex -s <<EOF
r!man true
1i
`echo "$str"`
.
"0r!echo "${str}"
wq! true.txt
EOF
```

`0r!echo "${str}"` might also be used as shorthand for `:0read!` or `:0r!` that you have likely used in `vi` mode (it is *literally* the same thing) but the `:` is optional here and some implementations do not support "r"ead address of zero.
"r"eading directly to the special line #0 (or from line 1) would automatically push everything "down", and then you just `:wq` to save your changes.

```
$ head -n 3 true.txt | nl -ba   
     1  +++ TOP +++
     2  TRUE(1)                          User Commands                         TRUE(1)
     3
```

Also, most classic `sed` implementations do not have extensions (like `\U&`) that `ex` should have by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*prod*" -exec sed -i '1i\line1\n  Line2\n     Line3\n' {} \;
```

I use it to resolve this.