# adding an html comment at the top in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cat

Hello i have to write a short program to take in an input and add it to the top of file and add a timestamp into the bottom of the file also in an html comment. just a little confused how to do this

```
echo "What would you like to add to the top of the file
read x
cat $x >> File1
```

But this is to add this at the end of the file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/9533736/975114

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# No go, if file not existant
test -f "$1" || exit 1

# Need a temp filename. Yes, this is racy.
test -f "$1.tmp" && exit 1

# Read text
echo 'What would you like to add to the top of the file?'
read COMMENT

# Exit on empty text
test -z "$COMMENT" && exit 1

# Write header
mv "$1" "$1.tmp"
echo -n "<!-- $COMMENT -->" > "$1"

# Write content
cat "$1.tmp" >> "$1"
rm "$1.tmp"

# Write footer
TS=$(date)
echo -e "\n<!-- $TS -->" >> "$1"
```

Comment: Use `mktemp` to avoid being racy.

Comment: Ofcourse I know. Point is, that from the OQ i guessed, this would be no problem and the example is much more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p 'What would you like to add at the top of the file?' header
cat - "$oldfile" <<< "$header" > "$newfile"
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' 'What would you like to add at the top of the file?' \
  '(hit ctrl-c on newline to commit, or ctrl-c to abort.)'
cat - "$oldfile" > "$newfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's where the shell's grouping construct comes in handy:

```
comment () { echo "<!-- $* -->"; }
read -p "what?" top
{ comment "$top"; cat $htmlfile; comment $(date); } > $htmlfile.new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "What would you like to add to the top of the file
read x
sed -i '1s/^/$x/' file
```