# How to edit the head of the huge txt file in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, vim

I tried to use vim to open the huge file to edit the head of it. I just want to add a line in the head. But opening it is a problem.
Any good way to edit the head of it ?

Comment: Check if this helps https://superuser.com/a/121424/728737

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533679/how-to-insert-a-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file

Comment: Place the line in a new file and append the existing one using shell redirection which can also append (`>>`). That way you don't have to open the file in an editor at all.

Comment: Why to use pipe or use subshell when sed can do it without all that clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash` and [`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
cat <(echo "This is the new line #1") bigfile | sponge bigfile
```

Comment: @yanachen, Click the URL in my answer, or install the `moreutils` package, (*i.e.* in *Debian/Ubuntu/etc.* run `apt install moretutils`.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't give the input file, I would assume that the input as followed, and add the test string "head added!!" to the head of each line.

```
$ cat test 
line 1
line 2
line 3

$ awk 'NR==1{$0="tested line 1\n"$0}1' test
tested line 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Modify `"tested line 1"`in the command `awk 'NR==1{$0="tested line 1\n"$0}1'` to your own input  test

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '1 i\New HEADER' bigfile
New HEADER
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Use `sed -i` flag to make changes persistent inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

Create file with headers only name it as 1.txt and place file in same directory as original file say for example your file is name as 2.txt

use cat command  as:

**cat 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt**

This will add headers from 1.txt and contents from 2.txt into 3.txt