# Insert the contents of a file as the first lines of a file; In bash (GNU)

Tags: bash, sed, kml

The specific task is to use the header of a KML file and insert it into hundreds of split up KML data files that do not have the header.

The KML header is multiple lines and specific spacing. I've found I can use Sed with the 'r' readfile option to grab the contents of a file containing the header. However when I insert the data with '1r' the header is placed in the file starting on the second line. sed doesn't seem to let me address 'line 0' to insert before. Insert mode would work, but I wouldn't be able to just grab the header format that is saved in a file and would need to script the entire header.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ./Split/*;
        do sed -i '1r KML_Header.txt' $i
done
```

The KML Header Looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <open>1</open>
            <gx:Track>
                 <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
```

The end result with the header will look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <open>1</open>
            <gx:Track>
                 <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:47:52Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.8216659 30.481537499999998 261</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:47:44Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.8216137 30.481513600000003 259</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:45:37Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.8216659 30.481537499999998 261</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:44:54Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.82162970000002 30.481479699999998 261</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:39:55Z</when>
```

However, this is what my current best command gets me:

```
<when>2017-11-16T11:47:52Z</when>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <open>1</open>
            <gx:Track>
                 <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <gx:coord>-97.8216659 30.481537499999998 261</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:47:44Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.8216137 30.481513600000003 259</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:45:37Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.8216659 30.481537499999998 261</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:44:54Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-97.82162970000002 30.481479699999998 261</gx:coord>
            <when>2017-11-16T11:39:55Z</when>
```

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this, for example here: https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533679/how-to-insert-a-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat file1 file2 > newfile` to prepend `file1` to `file2`. Do this in a loop.

```
for i in Split/*
do
    cat KML_Header.txt "$i" > "$i.new" && mv "$i.new" "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thank you @barmar for the quick response and simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying awk.  With GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'FNR==NR{hdr=hdr "\n" $0; next} FNR==1{print substr(hdr,2)} 1' inplace=0 header inplace=1 ./Split/*
```

How it works:

- `-i inplace`

  This tells awk to change files in-place.
- `FNR==NR{hdr=hdr "\n" $0; next}`

  This tells awk that, when reading the first file (header), it should save the contents in the variable `hdr`, skip the rest of the commands, and jump to the `next` line.
- `FNR==1{print substr(hdr,2)}`

  This tells that, when it starts a new file, it should first print the header (minus the unneeded initial newline in variable `hdr`).
- `1`

  This is awks cryptic shorthand for print-the-current-line.

#### Example

```
$ cat >header
1  
2
3
$ cat >file1
4
5
6
$ cat >file2
44
55
66
```

Using our command to change the files in-place:

```
$ awk -i inplace 'FNR==NR{hdr=hdr "\n" $0; next} FNR==1{print substr(hdr,2)} 1' inplace=0 header inplace=1 file*
$ cat file1
1
2
3
4
5
6
$ cat file2
1
2
3
44
55
66
```

Hat tip to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar).

Comment: There's a better way that doesn't require rewriting the header file. Put `inplace=0` before `header` and `inplace=1` after it.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html for the details of how inplace works in GNU awk.

Comment: @Barmar Still better.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @John1024 I was able to get this one to work. I really appreciate the detailed explanation of the segments, too. I'm always interested in learning the seemingly endless options of awk and sed. I do prefer the more simple approach from Barmar though.