# GIMP 2: how to batch assign sRGB profile to a lot of images into various subfolder

Tags: batch-file, gimp, srgb

I've an entire tree with PNG images

I need to 
- open
- assign sRGB profile
- close

to every of them

(about 2000 images)

Is there a way to do this via gimp 2?

Comment: It could be done via GIMP scripting - but if the only task you will perform is this one, maybe imagemagick is more handy, as  per @aneroid's answer

Comment: could you write me down an example of something like 
for each (folder)
  for each (subfolder)
    for each (photo)
     open(photo)
     assignRgb
     close

I never used GIMP scripting

Comment: I've not a linux machine ... sorry ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`imagemagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to do this. [Example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#color_profile):

```
convert rgb_image.jpg +profile icm \
        -profile sRGB.icc  -profile USCoat.icm cmyk_image.jpg
```

`mogrify` is the standard command iirc. And [here's an example doing a similar thing](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16470#p60137):

```
FOR /R %%a IN (*.jpg) DO mogrify -profile sRGB.icc "%%a"
```

Linux/[bash recursive directory loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638874/how-to-loop-through-a-directory-recursively) examples:

```
for f in $(find /tmp -name '*.png'); do mogrify $f ... ; done
```

(replace the `...` with your mogrify command, `$f` is the file)

Comment: Imagemagick is **[available on Windows](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows)** too. The first FOR is a windows loop, the second is in linux. Structure of Windows version of that command is: `FOR /R %%a IN (*.png) DO mogrify -profile sRGB.icc "%%a"`. The convert will also be available on both.

Comment: You might want to mention that `mogrify` will convert the file in-place, i.e. *override* the original file, unless one uses the `-format` option to pick a different file suffix. Source: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php