# Portable solution to loop through a directory recursively in bash 3.2

Tags: shell, unix, sh, portability

I want to loop recursively through *every file and directory* below an specified path and echo that file/directory's *owner* and *name*.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638874/how-to-loop-through-a-directory-recursively) to be a good reference, but I would like to know if there is a `bash 3.2` portable and simpler solution to the problem. A solution without using `find` would be excellent.

I also discovered there is `shopt -s globstar`, but I don't know whether it is portable or not.

If you look at my script, you will see that `log_owners` simply loops over `$@`, so maybe the problem is in my glob pattern. I thought `log_owners $root/**` would loop through everything, but it didn't.

```
# OSX check.
darwin() {
  [ $(uname) = "Darwin" ]
}

# Get file/directory's owner.
owner() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    if darwin; then
      stat -f "%Su" "$1"
    else
      stat -c "%U" "$1"
    fi
  fi
}

log_owners() {
  for file in $@; do
    echo $(owner "$file")"\t$file"
  done
}
```

I am using `sh`/`bash 3.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just realized the rather obvious (using recursion):

```
loop() {
  for file in $1/**; do >/dev/null
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      loop "$file"
    elif [ -e "$file" ]; then
      echo $(owner "$file")"\t$file"
    fi
  done
}
```

And it *seems* to be working alright.

Comment: try running `time find /base/dir -ls` vs `time loop /base/dir` or a reasonably large dir structure. The hh:mm:ss info at the end will help you decide if this is a good approach or not. Also, you didn't define portable. Portable as in POSIX compatible, or as /bin/sh compatible, or as you seem to be saying portable='oldest possible version of bash'. ;-) Good luck!

Comment: I see, I think I meant `/bin/sh` compatible. I think the recursive functions although simple is really slow.

Comment: As it stands, it is not /bin/sh compatible.  The `$( )` syntax, the globstar syntax, the 'owner' command are not /bin/sh.   What operating systems/machines will this be running on?

Comment: Thanks! @BradLanam Mac and Linux flavors.

Comment: Well, I think you are probably just fine w/the bash script you have then.   Having it bash-compatible should be ok.