# BASH while loop and qt-faststart

Tags: linux, bash, qt-faststart

I am not very familiar with bash scripting, so I need a small help from you guys.

I have a directory on my Gentoo server with several hundred videos and every video has a date in its name *(09092015.mp4, 10092015.mp4 etc.)*. I need a while loop that will copy all those files on new location with qt-faststart and keep their original name.

EDIT:

I have tried this code.

```
filename=${*.mp4}

while true;

qt-faststart $filename /backup/$filename
fi
done
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far, StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. People will gladly help you with specific problems you might encounter, but you need to show some effort on your own first.

Comment: That's certainly an attempt in the right direction. Have a look around this site (and the general internet) for how to operate over a set of files with a loop. This isn't quite it.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution. If this is needed to be done in PHP or Java it wouldn't be a problem. But, as I said before, it needs to be in BASH. I'll keep trying.

Comment: if you want a version that will work in all cases, search for `[bash] find -print0 while `. If you're certain the filenames will always be as described, search for `[bash] for done` Good luck.

Comment: See [How to iterate over files in directory with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [iterate over the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash) and run  `qt-faststart`:

```
for filename in *.mp4; do
  qt-faststart $filename /backup/$filename
done
```

If you want to include files in sub directories you can use [`find`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638874/how-to-loop-through-a-directory-recursively-to-find-files-with-certain-extension):

```
for filename in $(find . -name '*.mp4'); do
  qt-faststart $filename /backup/$filename
done
```

Comment: Great, this is it. Just what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.