# How to recursively traverse a directory tree and find only files?

Tags: bash, file, directory

I am working on a `scp` call to download a folder present on a remote system. Downloaded folder has subfolders and within these subfolders there are a bunch of files which I want to pass as arguments to a python script like this:

```
scp -r researcher@192.168.150.4:SomeName/SomeNameElse/$folder_name/ $folder_name/
echo "File downloaded successfully"
echo "Running BD scanner"
for d in $folder_name/*; do
        if [[ -d $d ]]; then
                echo "It is a directory"
        elif [[ -f $d ]]; then
                echo "It is a file"
                echo "Running the scanner :"
                 python bd_scanner_new.py /home/nsadmin/Some/bash_script_run_files/$d
        else
                echo "$d is invalid file"
                exit 1
        fi
done
```

I have added the logic to find if there are any directories and excluding them.  However, I don't traverse down those directories recursively.

Partial results below:

```
File downloaded succesfully
Running BD scanner
It is a directory
It is a directory
It is a directory
Exiting
```

I want to improve this code so that it traverses all directories and picks up all files. Please help me with any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go through the trouble of using `globbing` for file matching but rather use `find` with is meant for this by using a process-substitution (`<()`) with a while-loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    # single filename is in $file
    python bd_scanner_new.py "$file"
done < <(find "$folder_name" -type f -print0)
```

Here, `find` does a recursive search of all the files from the mentioned path to any level of sub-directories below. Filenames can contain blanks, tabs, spaces, newlines. To process filenames in a safe way, find with `-print0` is used: filename is printed with all control characters & terminated with NUL which then is `read` command processes with the same de-limit character.

Note; On a side note, always double-quote variables in `bash` to avoid expansion by shell.

Comment: Why use a `while`/`read` loop to parse the output of `find` (and using non-standard features) instead of using `find`'s `-exec` switch? `:)`.

Comment: If the directory has a huge number of files and the function that is executed per file is slow then using find will create a large pipe file or consume a large amount of memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `shopt -s globstar` in Bash 4.0+:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob
cd _your_base_dir
for file in **/*; do
  # will loop for all the regular files across the entire tree
  # files with white spaces or other special characters are gracefully handled
  python bd_scanner_new.py "$file"
done
```

Bash manual says this about `globstar`:

> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will
>   match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If
>   the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories
>   match.

More `globstar` discussion here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching