# Rename files based on pattern in path

Tags: unix, rename, mv

I have thousands of files named "DOCUMENT.PDF" and I want to rename them based on a numeric identifier in the path. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have access to the rename command.

Three examples:

```
/000/000/002/605/950/ÐÐ-02605950-00001/DOCUMENT.PDF
/000/000/002/591/945/ÐÐ-02591945-00002/DOCUMENT.PDF
/000/000/002/573/780/ÐÐ-02573780-00002/DOCUMENT.PDF
```

To be renamed as, without changing their parent directory:

```
2605950.pdf
2591945.pdf
2573780.pdf
```

Comment: *I don't seem to have access to the rename command*, you mean you don't have the ability to execute the `mv` command? If the original files are in `/000/000/002/...` what folder is that based from? The current directory, or the root? Where do you want the resulting files to go?

Comment: Yes, I can execute mv or cp. The original files are from the current directory (not root). The resulting files can go to the current directory. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `mv` is how you "rename" a file in Unix. You're **m**o**v**ing it to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, and then use the `mv` command

```
for file in *
do
  num=$(awk -F "/" '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt | cut -d "-" -f2);
  mv "$file" "$num.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `globstar` in Bash 4.0+:

```
cd _your_base_dir_
shopt -s globstar               
for file in **/DOCUMENT.PDF; do # loop picks only DOCUMENT.PDF files
  # here, we assume that the serial number is extracted from the 7th component in the directory path - change it according to your need
  # and we don't strip out the leading zero in the serial number
  new_name=$(dirname "$file")/$(cut -f7 -d/ <<< "$file" | cut -f2 -d-).pdf

  echo "Renaming $file to $new_name"

  # mv "$file" "$new_name" # uncomment after verifying
done
```

See this related post that talks about a similar problem: [How to recursively traverse a directory tree and find only files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799938/how-to-recursively-traverse-a-directory-tree-and-find-only-files)