# Iterating through all folders of an undefined amount of subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

I am in need of a way to script an iteration through an undefined amount of sub-directories.

I'm using kornshell to and awk. I've stripped the problem to this:

```
for file in $FILEPATH/*.txt
do
    awk '
        { 
            #some awk commands
        }
    '
done
```

So I need to change `$FILEPATH/*.txt` so it drills into directories until the end, then the loop iterates through all text files, backs out a directory and iterates through text files once more until no more directories or text files were untouched.

For context, I need to parse through a database and run some commands on certain files. So these file structures could go on for a while.

Comment: Are you aware of `find`?

Comment: I'm unsure how to use it for exactly what I need. The undefined amount of sub-directories is what is so weird about this.

Comment: That is what find is made for. https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html Take the time to read and experiment.

Comment: `find` syntax is weird and picky.  `find "$FILEPATH/" -type f -name *.txt`. Not sure about ksh syntax of for-loop, but in Bash it would be `for n in $(find "$FILEPATH/" -type f -name *.txt);do`...Note the trailing slash on FILEPATH, though it could be part of the variable value instead.

Comment: Okay thank you both, I've been messing with find. I think I'm close to getting it right, just need to tie everything together.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to loop through a directory recursively to delete files with certain extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4638874/45249)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your script like below it will work for your (in place of `.` put your path like `/tmp/my/personal/`. This is from where you want to search files:-

```
 FILEPATH=$(find . -name "*.txt")
 for file in $FILEPATH
 do
    echo $file
    awk '
    { 
        #some awk commands
    }
'

 done
```

Comment: This will fail if files have space, tab, or newline in their name.  For example: `one two.txt` will be treated like two files, `one` and `two.txt`, due to word splitting.

Comment: Added [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49214202/6862601) that handles the word splitting issues adequately.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid struggling with filenames including blank (or other disturbing things)
See [Bash Pitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec awk '{ ... }' {}  \;
```

- `.` start the search in the actual directory
- `-name` limit the search to a pattern
- `-type` limit the search to files
- `-exec` execute a command for each file found
- `{}` insert the filename here
- `\;` terminate the command. Escaped, so that the shell does hand it over to `find`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this in Bash is to turn on `globstar` option and use a glob to loop around:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$FILEPATH" || { printf '%s\n' "Cant' change directory to '$FILEPATH'"
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.txt; do
  # the awk code
  awk '...' "$file"
done
```

This is immune to [world splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), i.e., it will work fine even if there are whitespace characters in file names.

If you have to use `find` to do this, then:

```
while read -d '' -r file; do
  awk '...' "$file"
done < <(find "$FILEPATH" -name '*.txt' -print0)
```